# Forgetting about the utils

Tags: programming-practices, coding-style, utilities

Let's say my language's standard library does not include `TrickyFunction()`. Since implementation seems quite trivial for me, I decide to create `utils` in the project and add such function, for others to use.

Next month another programmer requires `TrickyFunction`. He doesn't expect it to exist, so instead he downloads and installs a library.

Year later, I require this function once again. However, I forget about the utils I've created and I instinctively google it. Unfortunately, positioning in google has changed and now another library is on top spot, introducing `FunctionTricky` which I install without a doubt.

---

**Is there any way to signal to future self and other programmers:**
***"In this project, we handle this problem with such solution"*?**

---

Things to consider:

- This issue can overlooked even during a code review, if I forget that I've added this function a year ago.
- Functions can be named differently in alternative libraries
- Utils folder can grow large, especially when working with new frameworks, where extra libraries does not exist yet.

Comment: Did you mean to transpose the words from `TrickyFunction` to `FunctionTricky`  in *"Unfortunately, positioning in google has changed and now another library is on top spot, introducing **FunctionTricky** which I install without a doubt."*?

Comment: Handling 3rd-party libraries and utils in such a way (by "Google and install") is just plain wrong in this and a gazillion of other (mainly legal and security) ways. I think you should start there to fix this.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Yes, my intention was to show, that code completion will not be helpful, if function is called differently in other libraries. Usually typing `tricky` will suggest `oneLibrary.tricky()` as wells as `second.tricky()`.

Comment: Issue appears when one library calls it `normalDistribution()` and second `gaussianDistribution()`

Comment: @tofro I completely agree that this is a bad approach for slower changing environments, f.e. c++ projects. However, while working on frontend, f.e. Angular, I find such approach quite inscribed in the nature of a framework. But of course I'm completely open for adapting new practices.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to promote code reuse and documentation?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/175066/how-to-promote-code-reuse-and-documentation)

Comment: No, I disagree. Not having a process that controls 3PP code influx into your project is dangerous, whatever your type of environment is. And such a process could also resolve your other problems.